# BuddyPress Xprofile fields to display on "wordpress user edit admin panel"

Tags: wordpress, field, admin, buddypress

I am building a buddypress/bbpress, website with xprofile registration fields. I am using New User Approve plugin to approve each users manually since we need to check information of each user before they get activated.

Problem here is, I am unable to check/view the xprofile field values in Wordpress user edit admin panel. All I have is the username change password, changing roles etc. I want the admin panel to display the extra information of the registered user so that I can check the info and approve . Anyone can help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be similar to this.. haven't tried the code though....
Replace the key value 'xprofile_key_birthday' with actual xprofile keys in Buddypress DB.

Note: This code only displays the values on the edit screen and doesn't insert or update anything.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'showmy_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'showmy_extra_profile_fields' );
function showmy_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label>xprofile_key_birthday</label></th>
            <td>
                <?php 
                if( function_exists( 'xprofile_get_field_data' ) ) {
                    $xprofile_value = xprofile_get_field_data('xprofile_key_birthday', $user->ID );
                }
                else {
                    $xprofile_value = '';
                }
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="xprofile_key_birthday" id="xprofile_key_birthday" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $xprofile_value ); ?>" class="regular-text" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...Where do I insert this? Is it in functions.php,and where do I get the xprofile keys in my code?

Comment: Yes, Paste these code inside the functions.php file under your current active theme folder. Make sure BuddyPress is installed. You can get the xprofile fields in the DB.

Comment: Have you created any extra fields in the buddypress backend for users ? Those are considered as xprofiles

Comment: I have tried the above code, I am able to see the Extra Profile Information on admin panel with profile fields, But I have a problem in profile key, I am unable to find it in my DB. I can see the Xprofile data fields but the fields shows like" Telephone No" " Designation" so on, I need to know whether I am supposed to replace xprofile keys like" Telephone No" or "telephone_no, .

Comment: It worked. I have inserted the code in function.php, but when I log out of admin i get error, Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...../functions.php:2673) in /home/.../wp-login.php on line 384

Comment: Ca you check by removing these piece of code from the functions.php file ? Can you paste the excat code in pastebin and provide the link ?

Comment: It worked , Thanks Subharanjan, the error was with space above this piece of code, I don't why the error for that space.

Answer (score 0):

I use the free [Wangguard plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wangguard/) on my BuddyPress/bbPress website. All I need to do is click on "Users" in the Wangguard menu on Wordpress dashboard sidebar and then click on "BP Profile" under the member username column. I can view and even edit the member profile from there. Hope it helps.